# Blend bottom of Image Background

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to implement a design but I don't know how I'll blend the image properly, I don't want the bottom of the Image to show just like the picture below
[image]

But this is what I get when I implement in react native after implementing
[image]

This is my code below, please what can I do to get the design properly

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#000" }}>
      <StatusBar
        backgroundColor="transparent"
        translucent={true}
        barStyle="light-content"
      />
      <ScrollView
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        directionalLockEnabled={true}
        bounces={false}
        scrollsToTop={false}
      >
        {/* this is the picture I am trying to blend */}
        <ImageBackground
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: 445
          }}
          source={require("../genny.png")}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: 460,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.40)",
              flexDirection: "column"
            }}
          >
            <Image
              resizeMode="contain"
              style={{
                width: 140,
                height: 31,
                left: 20,
                marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight + 10,
                alignSelf: "center"
              }}
              source={require("../kl.png")}
            />
            <ScrollView />
            <Text
              style={{
                fontFamily: "bn",
                color: "#FCAA4A",
                letterSpacing: 2,
                alignSelf: "center",
                fontSize: 60
              }}
            >
              LIONSHEART
            </Text>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: "row",
                width: 155,
                height: 14,
                alignSelf: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "space-between"
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: "#746E6E",
                  fontSize: 11,
                  fontFamily: "camptonBold"
                }}
              >
                2019
              </Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "#746E6E",
                  height: 4,
                  width: 4,
                  borderRadius: 2
                }}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: "#746E6E",
                  fontSize: 11,
                  fontFamily: "camptonBold"
                }}
              >
                1hr34mins
              </Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "#746E6E",
                  height: 4,
                  width: 4,
                  borderRadius: 2
                }}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: "#746E6E",
                  fontSize: 11,
                  fontFamily: "camptonBold"
                }}
              >
                Drama
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                width: 50,
                backgroundColor: "#FCAA4A",
                height: 20,
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                flexDirection: "row",
                marginTop: 12,
                paddingLeft: 10,
                paddingRight: 10,
                alignItems: "center",
                alignSelf: "center"
              }}
            >
              <Image
                resizeMode="stretch"
                style={{ width: 16, height: 16 }}
                source={require("../play.png")}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: "white",
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontFamily: "camptonBold"
                }}
              >
                PLAY
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later solved my issue, but I added about 300 new lines of code, I created 20 views and made their position absolute, then I made their opacity reduce by `0.02` i.e `0.90` then `0.88` then I made their top margin to reduce by 10, i.e `410` then `400`, I did this all the way to 0.00, so it created a blending image from bottom to top,Then I made all the text in the `<ImageBackground/>` absolute and coded their top margin too, it wasn't easy but I got it, this is the result below

[image]

This is the new code

```
 render() {

return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#000'}}>
   <StatusBar backgroundColor='transparent' translucent={true} barStyle='light-content'/>
   <ScrollView 
  keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                                                     showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                                                     automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                                                     directionalLockEnabled={true}
                                                     bounces={false}
                                                     scrollsToTop={false}>
   <ImageBackground
    style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 445,
    }}
    source={require('../genny.png')}>

     <Image resizeMode="contain"
                               style={{width: 140, height: 31,
                               marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight+10, alignSelf: 'center' }}
                               source={require('../kl.png')}/>
    <ScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
    </ImageBackground>
    <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 1,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.00)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
    <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 3,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
    <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 5,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.04)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
    <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 10,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.06)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 20,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.08)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 30,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.10)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 40,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.12)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 50,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.14)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 60,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.16)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 70,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.18)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 80,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.20)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 90,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.22)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 100,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.24)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 110,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.26)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 120,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.28)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 130,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.30)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 140,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.32)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 150,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.34)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 160,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.36)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 170,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.38)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 180,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.40)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 190,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.42)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 200,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.44)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 210,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.46)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 220,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.48)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 230,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.50)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 240,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.52)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 250,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.54)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 260,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.56)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 270,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.58)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 280,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.60)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 290,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.62)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 300,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.64)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 310,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.66)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 320,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.68)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 330,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.70)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 340,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.72)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 350,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.74)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 360,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.76)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 370,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.78)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: +79531727897 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.80)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 390,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.82)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 400,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.84)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 410,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.86)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 420,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.88)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
  <View style={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 10,position: 'absolute',top: 424,left: 0,
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)', 
     flexDirection: 'column'
    }}></View>
    <Text style={{fontFamily: 'bn', color: '#FCAA4A', letterSpacing: 2, alignSelf: 'center',position: 'absolute',
    top: 360,
    fontSize: 60}}>LIONSHEART</Text>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: 155, height: 14, alignSelf: 'center',position: 'absolute',
    top: 420,
    alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
     <Text style={{color: '#746E6E', fontSize: 11, fontFamily: 'camptonBold'}}>
         2019
     </Text>
     <View style={{backgroundColor: '#746E6E', height: 4, width: 4, borderRadius: 2}}>

     </View>
     <Text style={{color: '#746E6E', fontSize: 11, fontFamily: 'camptonBold'}}>
         1hr34mins
     </Text>
     <View style={{backgroundColor: '#746E6E', height: 4, width: 4, borderRadius: 2}}>

     </View>
     <Text style={{color: '#746E6E', fontSize: 11, fontFamily: 'camptonBold'}}>
         Drama
     </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{width: 50, backgroundColor: '#FCAA4A', height: 20, justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
      flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 12, alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center',position: 'absolute',
    top: 430,}}>
        <Image 
                      resizeMode="stretch" style={{width: 12,height: 12,}}
                     source={require('../play.png')}/>
        <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 10,
                 fontFamily: 'camptonBold'}}>PLAY</Text>
      </View>
 );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code snapshot it will help to achieve design which is mention above

I have also added [snack.expo.io](https://snack.expo.io/BJvoPZ0vE)

You can change colors and Images according to your requirement.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {ScrollView,Image,ImageBackground, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1,}}>


        {/* this is the picture I am trying to blend */}
        <ImageBackground
          style={{
          paddingBottom:30,
            width: "100%",
             backgroundColor:'#070707',
          flex:1
          }}
          source={require("./assets/snack-icon.png")}
          resizeMode="contain"
        >
          <View
            style={{
           height:'100%',
     alignContent:'center',
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.40)",

            }}
          >
            <Image
              resizeMode="contain"
              style={{
                marginTop:60,
                width: 140,
                height: 31,
                              alignSelf:'center',


              }}
             source={require("./assets/snack-icon.png")}
            />

            <Text
              style={{
                 marginTop:430,
                fontFamily: "bn",
                color: "#FCAA4A",
                alignSelf:'center',
                alignContent:'center',
                justifyContent:'center',
                letterSpacing: 2,
            alignItems:'center',
                fontSize: 50
              }}
            >
              LIONSHEART
            </Text>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: "row",
                width: 155,
                height: 14,
                justifyContent:'space-evenly',
                bottom:0,
                 marginTop:10,
                alignSelf: "center",
                alignItems: "center",

              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  fontSize: 11,
                  fontFamily: "camptonBold"
                }}
              >
                2019
              </Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "#746E6E",
                  height: 4,
                  width: 4,
                  borderRadius: 2
                }}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  fontSize: 11,
                  fontFamily: "camptonBold"
                }}
              >
                1hr34mins
              </Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "#746E6E",
                  height: 4,
                  width: 4,
                  borderRadius: 2
                }}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: "#ffffff",
                  fontSize: 11,
                  fontFamily: "camptonBold"
                }}
              >
                Drama
              </Text>
            </View>

          </View>

        </ImageBackground>


          <View
              style={{

                backgroundColor: "#FCAA4A",
                height: 20,
    position:'absolute',
             bottom:0,
             marginBottom:50,
               alignItems:'center',
               alignSelf:'center',
                flexDirection: "row",
                padding: 15,               
              }}
            >
              <Image
                resizeMode="stretch"
                style={{ width: 16, height: 16 }}
                 source={require("./assets/snack-icon.png")}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: "white",
                  marginLeft:8,
                  fontSize: 14,
                  alignItems:'center',
                  fontFamily: "bold"
                }}
              >
                PLAY
              </Text>
            </View>

    <View
              style={{

          justifyContent:'center',
             width:'100%',

                backgroundColor: "#3f3f3f",
                height: 20,
               alignItems:'center',
               alignSelf:'center',
                flexDirection: "row",
                padding: 15,               
              }}
            />


      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```